# AWS Cloudformation - Importing Jinja defined variables in YAML files

Tags: amazon-web-services, jinja2, aws-cloudformation

I have some Cloudwatch Alarms generated in the Jinja files. I wans to use one of those alarms in the YML files for the cloudformation. Simply putting `DependsOn` doesn't work as the processign fails with the error saying

`"StatusReason": "Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [ABC.Alarm] in the Resources block of the template",`

What is the way to import Jinja variables in the YML files for Cloudformation deployments?

Edit:

Our configurations contain both YML as well as Jinja files and I am not looking to replace the complete template. But just to use a parameter defined in Jinja files.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways for using yaml templates to be replaced by Jinja.

- [J2Cli](https://github.com/kolypto/j2cli) - bash utility that will need minimum code. [Interesting article for this](http://priocept.com/2017/07/18/taming-cloudformation-with-yaml-and-jinja2-templating-part-1/)
- Use Python (jinja module) + bash.

  - [Look here](https://hk.saowen.com/a/6f9ab76e04fc47aab74352e943713ef1f9aaaad9d146638ac0939f319306617b)

Comment: I am not looking to replace the complete template. But just to use a parameter defined in Jinja files.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to generate the CloudFormation templates yet. Better make use of [CloudFormation parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html)

You could use [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/) to pre-process and even to "execute" the templates.

Ansible has cloudformation module and you can pass it the name of the stack you want to create/update and you can pass template parameters.

in Ansible playbook `experiments.yml`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - cloudformation:
        stack_name: experiments
        template: experiments-stack.yml
        template_parameters:
            MyParameter: MyParameterValue
```

CloudFormation stack template `experiments-stack.yml`:

```
...

Parameters:
    MyParameter:
        Type: String

Resources:
    Something:
        Type: ...
        Properties:
        PropertyName: !Ref MyParameter
```

Run the playbook with `ansible-playbook ./experiments.yml`